# The maven option is not being listed in eclipse, even if the maven is installed

Tags: eclipse, maven, ubuntu

I have installed maven in my ubuntu but while creating a new project in eclipse, the maven option is not being listed.

"file -> new -> other" selection is not listing the 'maven' option in eclipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need to install M2E Eclipse plugin instead only Maven.  Installing Maven only give you the command line tools.  It has nothing to do with Eclipse integration

Comment: Thanks a lot Adrian as it is working now after installing the plugin mentioned by you.